# invalid character name at (1)

Tags: compilation, fortran

I am trying to compile a fortran code. It will analyze an X file in an Y directory and then create a new file Z with the results. But there is something wrong occurring.

When I write the directory I see that it is too much for one line and then I try to continue it in the next one doing this:

```
  namech='/home/matheus/Documents/UFABC/IC/Spectra/Elliptical/'
  +          'espec.fits'
```

But, when I try to compile using the command

> gfortran Codigo.f -o TESTE -Lcfitsio -lcfitsio

I get this error message:

> ```
>  +          'espec.fits'                                           
>   1
> ```
>
> Error: Invalid character in name at (1)

Can someone help me? Actually I do not know what this error is. The directory is 100% right. And when I move the archives to a simpler directory to be able to write everything in one line, it works! So is there something wrong with the "+"?

Thank you.

## Edit1

Actually, when I add "&" in the end of the line, it gives me this error message:

> ```
>  namech='/home/matheus/Documents/UFABC/IC/Spectra/Elliptical/'&    
>  1
> ```
>
> Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
>   Codigo.f:60.7:
>
> ```
>  +          'espec.fits'                                           
>   1
> ```
>
> Error: Invalid character in name at (1)

And with "//":

> ```
>  namech='/home/matheus/Documents/UFABC/IC/Spectra/Elliptical/'//   
>                                                                    1
> ```
>
> Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
>   Codigo.f:60.7:
>
> ```
>  +          'espec.fits'                                           
>   1
> ```
>
> Error: Invalid character in name at (1)

## Edit2

Thank you so much for helping me. Well, I solved the problem switching to the ".f90" form.

Just one more question: do you know why it does not recognize the "c" for comments in the code? Thank you again! :)

Comment: It doesn't recognize the `C` in comments because comments in the free-form are done using `!`. You have to change them, or correct just your original problem and stick with the fixed-form source.

Answer (score 4):

This part of your compilation statement:

```
gfortran Codigo.f
```

will treat the source file, with its `.f` suffix, as fixed form source.  This means that a continuation line is indicated by any character (other than a blank or a `0`) in column 6.

However, the error message you get suggests that the `+` in the second line of your snippet is not in column 6 and that the compiler is treating it as the initial character in a new entity name for which it is not valid. The fact that the `+` is aligned, vertically, with `n` in the previous line strengthens my suspicion that this may the root of your problem.

Adding the ampersand, as suggested in a now-deleted answer, doesn't actually help in this case if you continue to tell the compiler that it is dealing with a fixed form source file.  `&` is only used for continuation in free form source files.  Adding the string-concatenation operator, `//`, doesn't help either since it is not followed by another string but a line ending. `//&` would help but is probably unnecessary.

I think you have 2 possible solutions, but choose only one:

1. Stick with fixed form and get the alignment right.
2. Change the file suffix to `.f90` which will cause `gfortran` to treat the source file as free-form.

If you go for option 2 (which I would recommend) you can then either use `&` at the end of the continued line or you could simply merge the lines.  In free-form the maximum line length is 132 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to High Performance Mark's answer:

If you continue with FORTRAN 77, most compilers have an option to increase the allowed line length, e.g., `-ffixed-form  -ffixed-line-length-none` for gfortran.    As already stated, Fortran >=90 has line length of 132, so you wouldn't need to split the line.

Finally, if you want to split the line in Fortran >=90, you need two ampersands.  In most cases you need one, but to split a string you need two:

```
namech='/home/matheus/Documents/UFABC/IC/Spectra/Elliptical/&
&espec.fits'
```