# Fortran string formatting issues

Tags: fortran

I'm having some issues coding in fortran for a school assignment. I'm trying to write a sentence all on one line (per request of the instructor), but I'm having format issues.

From my understanding I need to use the & to concat the two lines (see below)
I've tried multiple variants of this but I'm having no luck.

```
'''[j87n896@csci305 fortran]$ gfortran money.f -o money
money.f:94:67:

   94 |          write(*,*) lunks,'lunkers',loons,'loonters',lits,'littles'   &
      |                                                                   1:

   95 |          &          poons, 'pooneys'
      |          1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)'''
```

Comment: There are two issues I can spot. Firstly, the ampersand is likely in the wrong column (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312759/invalid-character-name-at-1) and secondly you are missing a comma in the list (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398512/compilation-error-invalid-character-in-name-at-1). Additionally, you may be trying free-form continuation instead of the fixed form one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312759/invalid-character-name-at-1).

Answer (score 1):

In case you are coding in *fixed form* - and I believe you are - line continuation is done by adding any non-zero and non-blank character in the sixth column of the second line:

```
      write(*,*) lunks,'lunkers',loons,'loonters',lits,'littles',
     +     poons, 'pooneys'
```

In the case above, I have used a `+`, but any non-zero/blank char in the 6th column of the second line will do it. You can also extend it to split into more lines by adding chars at the 6th column of the third line, fourth line and so on.

In case you are coding in *free form*, the continuation is done by adding  a `&` in the end of the first line and in the beginning of the next line (although this last one is not always required):

```
write(*,*) lunks,'lunkers',loons,'loonters',lits,'littles', &
& poons, 'pooneys'
```

You may benefit from reading this unofficial copy of the [Fortran Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf). Item 6.3.2.4 describes continuation in free format, while item 6.3.3.3 describes continuation in fixed format (which I believe to be your case). You **should not** expect to understand every single thing you read there, but the sooner you start to try, the sooner it will make some sense for you.

Also, in your example **there is a comma missing right after 'littles'**. I've fixed that in both examples. Check it out.

Comment: I've tried to use `&` in both continued and continuing lines in free format and it compiled and ran without any error or warning (gfortran 8). I'm not sure if it is standard. Anyway, I removed the part of the answer that said having `&` in both lines was not allowed.

Comment: It's standard to have on both lines: it's actually _mandated_ in some cases.

Comment: Just checked the standard at 6.3.2.4. It is true!! :o

Comment: I believe a good text book is a better resource for a normal learner (say, Modern Fortran Explained).

Comment: Thank y'all so much for the help. Much appreciated!!